# How to enable scripting in Tomcat 8 for RDF4J Workbench 2.2.4?

Tags: tomcat, scripting, rdf4j

In order to create an RDFstore I have installed RDF4J server and RDF4J-Workbench 2.2.4 in Tomcat 8 (in Tomcat 8 I have deployed the relatives .war files of eclipse-rdf4j-2.2.4-sdk) in WIN10.

I have already configured Tomcat 8 by enabling the CGI and SSi servlets and the relatives mappings in `CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml` but workbench indicates the same message:

> Scripting is not enabled. The Open RDF Sesame Workbench application requires scripting to be enabled in order to work properly.

At the same time, in the `CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.2017` I receive the following:

> ...WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.eclipse.rdf4j.workbench.proxy.ServerValidator.checkServerPrefixes server URL null does not have a prefix file: http: https:....

Please for any idea about script enabling in Tomcat and the warning above.

Comment: At a guess, the "scripting" error has nothing to do with Tomcat or RDF4J configuration, but is a browser error. Presumably, your browser is not configured to allow JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicating scripting must be enabled is referring to your browser settings. Do you know how to enable scripting in your browser?

The checkServerPrefix error is referring to a null server setting, which is really just complaining about not having a server setup (yet).

Comment: Safari and Chrome that I use, are configured to allow javascript. The problem above still remain the same.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console (in developer tools)?